# Showing tooltip with two or more stack columns

Tags: highcharts

When I select a column, I want to show a tool-tip with only the values for the specific stack selected, but I'm showing all values for the two stacks (2012 and 2013).

Can I configure the tool-tip to show only one stack value?

If I cannot do it, how can I show the stack label into the tool-tip(2012 or 2013)?
I tried to use point.series.stack, but I'm getting a undefined value. Is it possible?

Code to show a tooltip over a stacked chart:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
    var s = '<b>'+ this.x +'</b>';
        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {
        s += '<br/>'+ point.series.name +': '+point.series.stack+':'+ point.y +'m';
                            });
            return s;
                          },
    shared : true
         }
```

[The complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/Kqumw/)

Thanks for your help.

Hi again

I followed your advice in order to show only the values for the same stack.

I have this formatter code:

```
tooltip: {

            formatter: function() {
                                            var tip = '<b>'+ this.x ;
                                            var stackSelected = this.point.series.options.stack;

                                            tip += '/'+stackSelected+'</b>';

                                            $.each(this.series.chart.series, function(i, s) {
                                                if(s.options.stack == stackSelected){
                                                    tip += '<br/><br/>';
                                                    tip += '<b>'+s.name+' : </b>'+s.yAxis;
                                                }

                                            });

                                            return tip;
                            },
            shared : false

        }
```

But I have problems in order to get the value for each serie.

Could you help me on this please?

Thanks in advance

I forgot the complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/Kqumw/4/

Answer (score 1):

I can get that i want

Thanks for your tips.

This is my tooltip code:

```
tooltip: {

            formatter: function() {
                            var tip = '<b>'+ this.x ;
                            var stackSelected = this.point.series.options.stack;
                            var categorySelected = this.point.category;

                            tip += '/'+stackSelected+'</b>';
                            tip += '<br/><br/>';

                            var index = 0;
                            $.each(this.series.chart.series, function(i, s) {
                                if(s.options.stack == stackSelected){

                                    $.each(s.data, function(j, point){
                                        if(point.category == categorySelected)
                                            tip += '<b>'+s.name+' : </b>'+point.y+'<br>';
                                    });

                                }

                            });

                            return tip;
                            },
            shared : false

        }
```

This is the complete code http://jsfiddle.net/Kqumw/5/

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to show different tooltip for the same category when shared is set for tooltip. If you want to show stack in tooltip, use `point.series.options.stack`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Kqumw/1/

If you want to show only one stack (full stack for hovered point), then disable shared (`shared: false`) and find on your own corresponding points for the same category and the same stack (by comparing category index/name from points and stack id from series).

Comment: How can i get a reference for the series array, or points array when I disable shared

Comment: Use `var series = this.point.series.chart.series`, then series will be array of all series.